# what if closedir() is not done after opendir() in C?

Tags: c

I want to understand what will happen if we don't do `closedir()` after doing `opendir()`, and what will happen if we keep on doing `opendir()`?

I tried to do `opendir()` continuously in my c program, but nothing seems to affect anything, internally will there be any memory leak when I do that?

Edit:

I know that we need to do closedir() actually, but internally wanted to understand what happens?

Comment: resources may have been allocated/reserved; locks may have been placed. Just do as the documentation says: close it after use.

Comment: the risk is to reach the max of dir handles allowed by process, not possible to open dirs anymore

Comment: If you really want to know for whatever reason, you can run a debugger or look at the implementation of dirent inside of glibc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have if you do this is a resource leak, which may be a memory leak in your process's memory space and is certainly a type of memory leak in the system as a whole (until your process's lifetime ends, in which case the resources it's holding are closed). At some point you'll exceed the per-process or system-wide limit on open file descriptors or other resources needed to manage an open directory, and further attempts to open directories (and likely files as well) will fail until you close some.

This is an inherent limitation, not an artificial one, because every open directory handle carries with it some state: which directory it's associated with, what the current position of the iterator is, etc. Keeping state inherently consumes memory of some sort.